# What's the principle that TypeScript includes @types without JS library?

Tags: javascript, typescript

By referring to `@types/foo` we can use the functionalities of a JavaScript library in TypeScript code. But why? It just defines a bunch of data types and interfaces, but the actual logic is still in the JS code. How can the code run without including the original JS library?

For example, to implement map services in TypeScript, we just include `@types/googlemaps` without the JS library `googlemaps`. Why is it so?

Comment: In general, no, that's not how it works.

Comment: Adding `@types/googlemaps` only includes the type definitions for that lib so that you can develop, it doesn't replace the lib. The lib still has to be present at runtime.

Comment: How would it be? Can you give a working [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that doesn't include googlemaps lib ?

Comment: Oops, I realized soon that my example of google maps is a wrong one, because I actually embedded its api tag in my html. In this case, there's no need to include an extra `googlemaps` npm package. Thanks for commenting!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code cannot run without the actual library. In general, you would have a development dependency on the `@types` and a full dependency on the actual library.

The types are there to back-fill type information for the library to give you the autocompletion, hinting, and type checking - but they don't actually give you anything at runtime.

There are some cases where a package will supply its own types, so you won't need the `@types` development dependency, but there are almost no cases where the reverse is true (the only exception would where `lib.d.ts` didn't include a feature supported by browsers etc, and you temporarily used a `@types` definition to let the compiler know about it).

Comment: Thanks so much! And I realized soon that my example of google maps is a wrong one, because I actually embedded its api tag in my html. In this case, there's no need to include an extra `googlemaps` npm package.